# Как решить проблему с установкой Visual Studio Community 2022?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, install, visual-studio-2022

В конце установки появляется окно с ошибкой: "Не удалось установить Microsoft.Net.4.8.KB5003306".
Чем лечить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Обязательно ли переустанавливать Windows, чтобы решить проблему? Совсем не хочется это делать

Comment: Ну зачем мелочится, можно сразу компьютер заменить... А если серьезно, указанный пакет это обновление для MS Fraemwork 4.8. Попробуйте его скачать и установить отдельно, возможно там будет описание причины ошибки. А вообще слишком мало вводной информации чтобы помочь с решением проблемы. И при чем здесь C++?

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что установщик Visual Studio не может узнать, какая версия у NET Framework сейчас установлена, и пытается обновить её, но не может, из-за того он устанавливает последнюю версию, которая уже была установлена (устанавливать дважды одну и туже версию нельзя).

Comment: @AlexeyVesker, когда я пытался обновить NET Framework до последней версии, установщик обновления выдавал, что последнее обновление уже установлено.

Comment: Удалите все фреймворки от 4 и старше и их обновления. Загрузите и установите последний (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).

Comment: @Akina, у меня Windows 10

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations)

Comment: У меня 528040, а последняя версия для Windows 10 - 528372

Comment: Пытался через NET Framework Repair Tool, не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему обновлением Windows